# mongoose find is not returning array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, find

my problem is following: when I am fetching data from database (mongoose) with `.find()` method it fetches it but it is not returning array, instead it is returning objects separated with comma, but i need to loop through array to map it and display each result separately, and i want to know why it is not returning array and how can i convert it to array? here is my code

```
await Zazani.find({zaza: {$regex: req.query.keyword, $options: 'i'}})
  .skip((limit * page) - limit)
  .limit(limit)
  .exec((err,zazans)=>{
        const count = ZazanLength.length; //another fetched data for determining length 
        const pages = (Math.ceil(count / limit) == 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(count / limit))
        res.render('search', {
            zazans,
            currentPage: page,
            totalPages: pages
        })
  })
```

and schema:

```
const ZazanSchema = new Schema({
   zaza: Schema.Types.String
})
```

and result:

```
{ _id: 5d6571aa4aca2d06a4bc785d, zaza: &#39;gela12&#39;, __v: 0 },
{ _id: 5d6572124aca2d06a4bc785e, zaza: &#39;gela12&#39;, __v: 0 }
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: its not usual, But in order to be 100% sure and always want array use aggregate instead.

Comment: you mean `Zazan.aggregate([$match: {} ])`

Comment: exactly, this is what i meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
await Zazani.aggregate()
  .match({zaza: {$regex: req.query.keyword, $options: 'i'}})
  .skip((limit * page) - limit)
  .limit(limit)
  .exec((err,zazans)=>{
        const count = ZazanLength.length; //another fetched data for determining length 
        const pages = (Math.ceil(count / limit) == 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(count / limit))
        res.render('search', {
            zazans,
            currentPage: page,
            totalPages: pages
        })
  })
```

Comment: `[object Object],[object Object], ...` this is returned data

Comment: and it must return array of objects

Comment: is this not array?

Comment: ok, I will be referring the document provided in the question and post the aggregate query.

Comment: oh sorry it worked i just stringified result and logged and it is array

Comment: thank you for answer but i can not get why `find is not working`

Comment: interesting, never faced such issue. But i always prefer aggreate over find. Reason we can add the new stage in the pipeline. also it make query more understandable, But this is my personal preference.

Comment: undestandable. more interesting is that find is not returning array in ZazanLenght query too

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `toArray` method:

```
Zazani.find({zaza: {$regex: req.query.keyword, $options: 'i'}})
 .skip((limit * page) - limit)
 .limit(limit).cursor()
 .exec().toArray(function(err, data) {
     console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: yes but is it usual that it is not returning array?

Comment: Well... Find should technically always return an array. However, I've had instances using `limit` and `sort` I'm forced to use `.toArray` I don't really understand the _why_ of this to be honest. And contrary to the comment above, I've had to use `toArray` in an aggregate as well.

Answer (score 0):

`.exec` function returns a promise, I think you don't have to pass callback in that.

```
var zazans = await Zazani.find({zaza: {$regex: req.query.keyword, $options: 'i'}})
    .skip((limit * page) - limit)
    .limit(limit)
    .exec();

const count = ZazanLength.length; //another fetched data for determining length 
const pages = (Math.ceil(count / limit) == 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(count / limit))
res.render('search', {
    zazans,
    currentPage: page,
    totalPages: pages
})
```

Comment: and it will return array?

Comment: then we dont need exec anyway

Comment: find returns an array always. I have never seen this problem before.

Comment: it still returns objects not array